# nbastatR works locally but does not show up in Shiny web

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, rstudio-server

I'm using a package called nbastatR to retrieve NBA stat data. For example,

```
teams_shots(teams = "Cleveland Cavaliers",seasons = 2023)
```

gives a shot data of Cleveland Cavaliers in 2023 season. However, it works locally when I try to display the table but does not show anything when I publish it on the web (same for the plots).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(nbastatR)



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  "Cavaliers",
  tableOutput('table')
  
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable(teams_shots(teams = "Cleveland Cavaliers",seasons = 2023))

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I first thought it was an environment problem.

```
Sys.setenv(VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE=500072)
```

But even though I included VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE=500072 in the .Renviron file, the table or the plots using the nbastatR package does not show up.

Is this because data from nbastatR package is too large to be deployed?

Comment: FYI, I tried `Sys.setenv("VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE" = 131072000)` (which is 128Mb) and it worked.

Comment: @SuNa Were you able to publish it on the web? I tried increasing from 500072 to 131072000 but it's still not displaying on the shiny web.